# How to optimise this MySQL SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working with the join plus union plus group by query, and I developed a query something like mentioned below:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        (SELECT countries_listing.id,
                countries_listing.country,
                1 AS is_country
         FROM countries_listing
         LEFT JOIN product_prices ON (product_prices.country_id = countries_listing.id)
         WHERE countries_listing.status = 'Yes'
           AND product_prices.product_id = '3521')
      UNION
        (SELECT countries_listing.id,
                countries_listing.country,
                0 AS is_country
         FROM countries_listing
         WHERE countries_listing.id NOT IN
             (SELECT country_id
              FROM product_prices
              WHERE product_id='3521')
           AND countries_listing.status='Yes')) AS partss
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY country
```

And I just realised that this query is taking a lot of time to load results, almost 8 seconds.

I was wondering if there is the possibility to optimize this query to the fastest one?

Comment: Make sure your table is indexed and you could use LIMIT X_number to limit the amount of results found. But am sure there are other solutions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about review of a working query and as such better fits to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see which indexes are being hit. I notice that the first inner query uses a `JOIN` whereas the second one doesn't, why?

Comment: You could also post it in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See @Mihai's formatting of your query - if you can ask questions in this way, it helps greatly, and reduces edit work.

Comment: @halfer In case you didnt know http://sqlformat.org/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the logic correctly, you just want to add a flag for the country as to whether or not there is a price for a given product.  I think you can use an `exists` clause to get what you want:

```
SELECT cl.id, cl.country,
       (exists (SELECT 1
                FROM product_prices pp
                WHERE pp.country_id = cl.id AND
                      pp.product_id = '3521'
               )
       ) as is_country
FROM countries_listing cl
WHERE cl.status = 'Yes'
ORDER BY country;
```

For performance, you want two indexes:  `countries_listing(status, country)` and 
product_prices(country_id, product_id)`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing such great idea but I also need to select those country rows as well that don't exist in product_prices table.

Kindly help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah man, its working fine I was just amazed and double minded with the query.

Thanks alot dude.

Comment: Note that correlated subqueries are not especially noted for being fast, and quoting product_id is almost certainly unnecessary! That said, deriving this query from the original is an impressive feat!

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how often it is executed, prepared statements could help. See [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for more information.